# NavigationController switching issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UINavigationController`, its root controller (`UITableViewController`) and an instance of `UIViewController` that is pushed to the top of Navigation when I click on a cell in Navigation Controller's root view (i.e. table view). The problem comes, when I swipe from a view controller to the root one. The selection doesn't disappear though I send  `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` message in its table view. If I click on the back button it works properly. How do I solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property of `UITableViewController` called `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`.

If you set that to YES (I believe you can access this in IB int eh inspector too) then it will stop this happening.

Comment: Yes, of course.


http://pastebin.com/fp2mwvMY - Root View Controller (for Navigation VC)
http://pastebin.com/hQdsDZUn - Parent class for each sub controller
http://pastebin.com/5jKk6tYc - A sub class of SecondViewController

Comment: Put that code `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;` in viewDidLoad not viewWillAppear. Everything looks fine though.

Comment: Eh, it's got more interesting. If I swipe fast to the right, selection doesn't disappear but if  I do it gradually then it becomes deselected. What can be the issue?

Comment: Okay, it was funny to come up with such an extraordinary issue at a glance, but, fortunately, it wasn't caused by any bug. I just forgot to deselect a selected cell in the root controller. Thank you! :-)